# How to search Segue Identifier in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a lot of `controller` in my `storyboard` and i am calling.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"someIdentifier" sender:self];
```

If i want to search the `controller` associate with `someIdentifier` in xcode storyboard then how can i do?

Is there any way or i have to click and check on all the `controller`?

Comment: I would search the XML source code (`Open As` | `Source Code`) for the name of the view controller and take it from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As suggest by Drux:**

The best way i found is search Segue Identifier in the XML source code (Open As | Source Code) for the name of the viewcontroller and take it from there.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's no way in code to find storyboard identifiers for a view controller / storyboard scene.

You could consider adding an additional target/build phase to your project that runs a script to extract the segue identifiers from the storyboard XML and convert into a file of constants you can import. Then you get runtime checking of the strings.

Something like this (for push segues):

```
grep -r -h  "kind=\"push\"" *.storyboard | sed -e 's/.*identifier="\(.*\)".*id=\".*/extern NSString * const XXXSegueName_\1;/' | sort | uniq  > "XXXSegueConstants.h"
grep -r -h  "kind=\"push\"" *.storyboard | sed -e 's/.*identifier="\(.*\)".*id=\".*/NSString * const XXXSegueName_\1 = @\"\1\";/' | sort | uniq  > "XXXSegueConstants.m"
```

should give you:

```
extern NSString * const HDCSegueName_PushMyViewController;
```

and

```
NSString * const HDCSegueName_PushMyViewController = @"PushMyViewController";
```

I'll leave other segue types as an exercise for the reader!

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct method to get a viewController by his segueIdentifier but you can have access to the destination controller in prepareForSegue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    DestinationViewController * nextVC = segue.destinationViewController; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a straightforward way to do it in the UIStoryboard but maybe you can get it from the code, implement prepareForSegue in the source view controller like this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender  {
    UIViewController * nextVC = segue.destinationViewController; 
    if ([segue.identifier compare:@"someIdentifier"] == NSOrderedSame) {
         NSLog(@"%@", [nextVC class]);
    }
}
```

This will print your destination view controller's name

Answer (score 0):

There is no way via public API but for testing you can use this private API:

```
id<NSObject> template = [cell performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"selectionSegueTemplate")];
  if (template) {
    [template performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"perform:") withObject:cell];
  }
```

source: https://github.com/soutaro/Obihiro

You might want to call selectRow before this in case you make use if indexPathOfSelectedRow in prepareForSegue.